# Margin right negative makes moves input to the right

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML to place a button inside an input ([JSFiffle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ksd9n4gr/)):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 400px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: -80px;
  padding: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

i {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

**Problem**

The [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ksd9n4gr/) I posted works great ...

But in my application when the negative margin right value is bigger then the icon width the input moves right and gets outside of the container with a space on the left:

[image: Input moving right]

I am not able to replicate this on JSFiddle but I wonder if someone has any idea what to look for because I have been trying everything and not able to solve it.

Comment: Your "jsFiffle" doesn't have any CSS. Also, what's `color: @green;`?

Comment: What are you expecting a negative margin to do?

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, just updated the JSFiddle link. It didn't save. Now it is working

Comment: @JamesCoyle The negative margin puts the icon over the input

Comment: Your implementation is really hacky IMO. You shouldn't really need a negative margin.

Comment: @JamesCoyle Could you suggest a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something more along these lines:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.search-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.search-field {
  flex: auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="search-input">
    <input class="search-field" type="text">
    <button class="search-button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution without flex ... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you didn't want a flex solution, how about removing the negative `margin-right` and replacing `width: 100%` with `width: 88%`.

That being said and since I'm a big fan of flexbox, the following is a different flex solution from James' offering:

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: flex; /* Added */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Added */
}

input {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  /* margin-right: -80px; */ /* Removed */
  padding: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* width: 100% */ /* Removed */
  flex: 0 1 100%; /* Added */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make the `input`'s container `position: relative` and the `button` `position: absolute`. Then you can move the `button` wherever you want relative to the container. I would suggest using something other than the `form` element, so that you can have more than one element in the `form`. I've added a simple wrapping `div`.

Then you set right to a little more than 0 so that the border(s) can be seen, and the top to half way down, less half the height of the button so it's centered vertically.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.search {
  /* Making the container relative... */
  position: relative;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* means you can absolutely position the button relative to that */
  position: absolute;
  /* make it one pixel off the right for the border */
  right: 1px;
  /* make it 50% - half its height to center it vertically */
  top: calc(50% - 14px);
}

i {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text">
    <button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```